# R cut function - where do breaks begin and end?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a numeric variable, `AGE`, in a dataset `d`. It's a bunch of ages as integers. Here's a snippet:

`1 2 3 4 5 6`

And so on up to age 89.  I need to convert this to a factor variable with nice little buckets for age groups, looking mainly at minors so those under 18 years old. Ultimately, I'm trying to get a little frequency table that displays age groups nicely. So to do this I've done the following:

`d$AGE_f <- cut(d$AGE, breaks = c(0, 6, 13, 17, Inf))`

Which works just fine. However, when I go to make my table using `table(fyc1997$AGE97X_f)`, the bucket labeling looks odd:

```
(0,6]    (6,13]  (13,17] (17,Inf]  

3297     4152     2253    23647
```

Where is the end point of each bucket if the end of the first bucket and the beginning of the second are both `6`? Shouldn't the buckets be (0,6] (7,13] (14,17] and (18,Inf] ?

Comment: this is the way `cut` displays intervals : `6]` is included, `(6` is excluded to avoid having `6` in 2 buckets. Works for any numeric type

Comment: Ahah! Thanks a million sir. I'll write that up in my own answer. (And credit you of course.)